# mysqljs with transactional processing

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have the following code in  my CustRepo that is not working, not showing any error log,

```
var addCustomer = function (customer) {
return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    let sqlString = 'call qins_Customer' + '(' +
        '"' + customer.Name + '"' + ',' +
        '"' + customer.Contact + '"' + ',' +
        '"' + customer.Address + '"' + ',' +
        '"' + customer.EmailAddress + '"' + ',' +
        '"' + customer.CustomerNotes + '"' + ',' +
        '"' + customer.MainTel + '"' + ',' +
        '"' + customer.Tel1 + '"' + ',' +
        '"' + customer.Tel2 + '"' + ',' +
        '@CustomerId'  + ');' +
        'select @CustomerId as CustomerId';
    console.log(sqlString);
    pool.getConnection.beginTransaction(function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('err');
            return reject(err);
        }
        connection.query(sqlString, function (err, CustomerId) {
            console.log(CustomerId);
            let result = CustomerId;
            if (err) {
                    connection.rollback(function (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    reject(err);
                });
            }
        });

        connection.commit(function (err) {
            if (err) {
                    connection.rollback(function (err) {
                    console.log('rejected');
                    reject(err);
                })
            } else { console.log('committed'); resolve(result); }
        });
    });
 });
}
```

If I remove the transaction processing and revert to non-transactional,
console.log of sqlString is

```
call qins_Customer("myCompany","Gary Gulp",
"Node Street Mocha MC229UG","gary@gmail.com","test888",
"01302 336 876",
"0153 2765 453","0134 5625 776",@CustomerId);
select @CustomerId as CustomerId
```

I get it working and I get table insertion and it produces the scope identity for Customer id (in Sql Server speak). Multiple statements is ON. My CustomerService module has this code

```
    let addCustomer = customerRepo.addCustomer(customer);
addCustomer
    .then(function (result) {
        resolve(result);
        return result || '-1';
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        return reject(err);
    })
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: **WARNING**: This code is full of [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Try to use something like [Sequelize](http://sequelizejs.com) that supports prepared statements with placeholder values to prevent this. It also has the side-effect of making your queries much more readable, and your code way more maintainable.

Comment: Hi tadman, yes I will do, this is just a proof of concept and not for production. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Sure, but you're working with really primitive tools if you're banging against the low-level driver. A tiny bit of abstraction helps you actually build your proof of concept more quickly.

Comment: @tadman you may be right, I will check it out. Still though I have no idea why the code is above not even logging an error.

Comment: Sequelize uses promises, that makes errors harder to ignore. With callback style you're responsible for intercepting and logging everything so it's very easy to miss something.

Comment: ok, I am looking into it now, cheers